# Js check if one or more vars are undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement, var

lets say i have multiple vars:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c;
var d = 4;
var e;
```

I want to check if one of them (or more) is empty, in this case var c and var e.
is it possible to check them all at once?

thanks!

Comment: use typeof. for e.g typeof c === 'undefined'

Comment: @Claudiu `var c; console.log(c);`.

Comment: What else can he mean by empty?

Comment: @Claudiu It's quite clear I think from his examples and from the comments on other answers.

Comment: @Claudiu: the safest bet for checking empty is to use typeof c === 'undefined'

Comment: Just do `if (c === undefiend)`. Using `typeof` for this is overkill, unless you actually allow `undefined` to be clobbered locally.

Comment: By empty do you mean undefined? Because `c` and `e` are undefined variables. If you mean that edit your question to say "undefined" other than "empty", some people seem to be confused by this (into thinking you mean empty string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If checking them all is your goal, then you should group them all up.

Try using an associative array instead.

```
var items = {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    d:4
};

//Check empty
if(items.c === undefined){
    console.log('c is empty');
}
```

if you iterate over items, you'll only get variables that have been set. So lets try this another way.

`null` would be another way of saying an item is empty, and maybe you actually want the variables to exists.

```
var items = {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:null,
    d:4,
    e:null
};

//Check empty
for(var item in items){
    if(items[item] === null){
        console.log(item, 'is empty');
    }
}
```

Comment: `{}` in javascript is not an associative array. You need `Map` for that.

Comment: @simonzack honestly I was speaking about the [abstract data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)

Comment: @simonzack: There is no `Map` in JavaScript currently. Some people call an object an associative array. It's not the best description, but the point is understood.

Comment: @cookiemonster https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @simonzack: ***This is an experimental technology, part of the Harmony (ECMAScript 6) proposal.***

Comment: @cookiemonster A lot of places implement it however, you could use a polyfill if you don't have it. Using `{}` directly is a poor choice. A better choice is to use `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: @simonzack should we expect someone who asks this to use a polyfill

Comment: @Gabs00 Ok point taken, I didn't downvote you btw if that's what you think I did.

Comment: @simonzack somehow I still got 6 out of 10 so I'm happy either way. But yours is a better answer imo, to get the job done.

Comment: @Gabs00: Your answer of restructuring to not use individual variables makes far more sense than creating a structure on the fly.

Comment: @simonzack: Using an object is a poor choice? There's nothing wrong with it. Using `Object.create(null)` will also have limited support if the intent is to avoid `Object.prototype` properties. I don't see any indication that the property names will be unknown in advance, so there's nothing wrong with a plain old object.

Comment: @cookiemonster I suppose you're right, in the context of this question. I just tend to say this since I've encountered some problems using `{}` in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c;
var d = 4;
var e;

[a, b, c, d, e].some(function(x){return typeof x === "undefined";});
```

I don't think javascript has introspection features, so you can't just find all the variables in the local scope.